# redux-presist not updating local storage

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have a basket reducer which contains my shopping basket and basket content would be something like this:

```
basket: {
    32012: {
        title: "foo",
        count: 1
    },
    32013: {
        title: "bar",
        count: 1
    }
}
```

I persist it with redux-persist, it's working good when a new object has been add or remove from basket array, but when I update a child like this:

```
basket: {
    32012: {
        title: "foo",
        count: 4
    },
    32013: {
        title: "bar",
        count: 5
    }
}
```

after refreshing page count would be 1 for each item!

here is my rootReducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import basketReducer from '../ducks/basket/reducers';
const basketPersistConfig = {
    key: 'basket',
    storage: storage,
};
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    basket: persistReducer(basketPersistConfig, basketReducer)
});
export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the reason of this issue is that when we update just a part of an object, persist would not update local storage, so I should update the whole object instead of count property.
so I change the structure of my basket reducer and separated the count and product from each other into two different sub reducers called products and badges, and mapped product count by key to the product in badges like this

```
basket: {
    badges: {
        3201: 3.
        3202: 4
    },
    products: {
        3201: {
            id: 3201,
            title: "foo"
        }
        3202: {
            id: 3202,
            title: "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//State shape
{
   'A':{},
   'B':{}
}
```

In my case the trick was in const newState = Object.assign({},state);

```
switch(action.type){
        case DELETE_CODE:
            const newState = Object.assign({},state);
            delete newState[action.payload.code];
            return newState;
...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your `basket` reducer has nested properties, it might be that `redux-persist` isn't merging the objects correctly when it hydrates.

In your `rootReducer` try adding:

```
//...previous code
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2'
const basketPersistConfig = {
  key: 'basket',
  storage: storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};
```